# Busca SQL especifica

Tags: sql, mysqli

Ola queria fazer uma busca no banco de dados com and que só traga a resposta se as condições forem atingidas código usado.

```
$sql2 ="SELECT * FROM `link` WHERE 1  LIKE ds_url_orig='https://www.frasesdobem.com.br/frases-incriveis' AND ds_email_link_modo='0'";
                $query2 = mysqli_query($link, $sql2) or die(mysqli_error());
                $show2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2);
                $email_type = $show2['ds_email_link_modo'];

                while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){
                    $email_type  =$rows['ds_email_link_modo'];
                    echo $email_type.'/';
                }
```

se ds_url_orig for encontrada e o ds_email_link_modo for igual ao consultado ele mostra, e caso uma delas for falsa ele n mostra resultado.
Porem o codigo continua mostrando  se uma condição for verdadeira alguém pode me ajudar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está usando o `LIKE` incorretamente.

Correto:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `link` 
WHERE ds_url_orig LIKE '%https://www.frasesdobem.com.br/frases-incriveis%' 
AND ds_email_link_modo = '0'
```

Também, se terá só números no `ds_email_link_modo`, geralmente não irá precisar de aspas, a não ser que seja algo muito específico.

```
AND ds_email_link_modo = 0
```

O `AND` obrigatoriamente obriga que o primeiro filtro seja obrigatório.

---

"Lendo" sua query, seria basicamente assim:

Traga tudo, da tabela `link`, onde `ds_url_orig` contenha `'%https://www.frasesdobem.com.br/frases-incriveis%'` e `ds_email_link_modo` é igual a `0`.

O `%` no inínio do `LIKE` significa "qualquer coisa antes", e o do final "qualquer coisa depois" (podendo ser retirado)